# Factory method which returns generic extending two types

Tags: java, generics, factory, multiple-inheritance

In this factory, which returns `Component`s which also implement a special interface, I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from SpiffyCombo to C" in `createSomethingSpiffy`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it expected that I have to cast `SpiffyCombo` to `C` here?

```
class Factory {
    public static <C extends Component & SpiffyComponent> C createSomethingSpiffy(Object... params) {
        C comp = new SpiffyCombo();
        // real method will be more complex
        return comp;
    }
}

class SpiffyTextField extends Component implements SpiffyComponent {
    public void wow() { ... }
}

class SpiffyCombo extends JComboBox implements SpiffyComponent {
    public void wow() { ... }
}

interface SpiffyComponent {
    void wow();
}
```

Comment: What would happen if we called `SpiffyTextField foo = Factory.<SpiffyTextField>createSomethingSpiffy()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can't get that far, it's a compile error on the `C comp = new SpiffyCombo()` line, before there's any chance to invoke it. Also, in reality, the specific return type will be determined by the parameters passed to `createSomethingSpiffy`.

Comment: That's what I meant. The compiler is preventing you from getting to that case.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to assign a value of a concrete type to a variable of a type parameter because you don't know what will be bound to it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, maybe I'm asking the wrong thing. We currently have a `createSomethingSpiffy` method which takes a database field name and returns a `SpiffyComponent` of a suitable type. I'm trying to modify it so I can at least use the result as a `Component` without casting; getting the exact subtype would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

A type parameter is really only useful from a call site (+/- a few cases). Within the scope of the type parameter, the type is basically its bounds. So although a `SpiffyCombo` fits the bounds of `C`, not every possible type bound to `C` is a `SpiffyCombo`. The compiler can therefore not let you use the value of either interchangeably.

You seem to want to achieve something like

```
abstract class HellaSpiffyComponent extends Component implements SpiffyComponent {}

public static HellaSpiffyComponent createSomethingSpiffy(Object... params) {...}
```

and makes your corresponding class extend `HellaSpiffyComponent` instead of extending `Component` and implementing `SpiffyComponent`.